# Pandas - Add new rows to dataframe with arithmetic

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a data frame (df) like so with a large number of rows and columns...

```
    v   w   x   y   ... z
0   a   p   1   1   ... 1
1   a   q   0   1   ... 0
2   b   p   1   1   ... 1
3   b   q   0   1   ... 0
4   c   p   1   1   ... 1
5   c   q   1   0   ... 1
```

I want to divide the value in every row where v is the same and w equals p by the sum every value in across columns in rows where column v is the same, and return this new value in a new row or column.
For example:

```
    v   w   x   y   ... z
0   a   p   1   1   ... 1
1   a   q   0   1   ... 0
2   a   r   1   0.5 ... 0.5
3   b   p   1   1   ... 1
4   b   q   0   1   ... 0
5   b   r   0.5 1   ... 0.5
6   c   p   1   1   ... 1
7   c   q   1   0   ... 1
8   c   r   1   0.5 ... 1
```

Where rows with r in column w have these proportions in them.

Alternatively, these proportions could be in new columns. Some values I would assume would be NaN or missing, which is fine.

```
    v   w   x   y   ... z   rx  ry  ... rz
0   a   p   1   1   ... 1   1   0.5 ... 0.5
1   a   q   0   1   ... 0   Nan Nan ... Nan
2   b   p   1   1   ... 1   0.5 1   ... 0.5
3   b   q   0   1   ... 0   Nan Nan ... Nan
4   c   p   1   1   ... 1   1   0.5 ... 1
5   c   q   1   0   ... 1   Nan Nan ... Nan
```

I can do this with a simple statement for one set of paired rows in a single column.

```
df.loc[df['v'] == 'a','rx'] = df.loc[df['v'] == 'a', 'x'].sum()
```

But I want to do this for a large data frame where making individual statements would take a lot of time. I know I can do this with loops, but I'm wondering is there an easier way? I just get the feeling that this can be done easily with numpy or pandas functions/statements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC I will `set_index` with columns v , then just slice what you need for *numerator* , the *denumerator* is the `sum` of all same value in v

```
df.set_index('v',inplace=True)

df=pd.concat([df,(df.loc[df.w=='p']/df.sum(level=0)).fillna('r')]).sort_index().reset_index()
df
Out[539]: 
   v  w    x    y    z
0  a  p  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  a  q  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  a  r  1.0  0.5  1.0
3  b  p  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  b  q  0.0  1.0  0.0
5  b  r  1.0  0.5  1.0
6  c  p  1.0  1.0  1.0
7  c  q  1.0  0.0  1.0
8  c  r  0.5  1.0  0.5
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great, except that any column that does not contain numbers is now filled with the value 'r' or whatever I put in fillna(). What if I want these NaN values to be filled with say the first value in w that has the same value in v (which was used as the index in this answer) as the row just created? Asking too much?

Comment: Change this part `(df.loc[df.w=='p']/df.sum(level=0)).fillna({'w':'r'})` @MatthewSnyder

Comment: Can I dynamically choose what to replace the NaN with? Like a value from another location in the dataframe? For example, just replace all NaN values with the value in the row above?

Comment: @MatthewSnyder that is `ffill`, BTW just kind remind , if this solve you problem ,do not forget to accept/ upvote it

Comment: Sorry, I will accept your answer as the correct one because you did technically answer my question. Sorry I came back asking for more. But ffill just uses the last valid instance, of which there are none for a column with no numbers.